# Split A/B Testing & Piwik visit count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, split, matomo, ab-testing

I have an A/B testing system (a RoR gem named [split](https://github.com/splitrb/split)) that redirects the visitor ([302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)) on either the page A or the page B by tossing a 50/50 coin. This systems has its own basic stats, which says that **our visits are equally distributed between A and B**.

We are tracking our pages with Piwik, to be able to retrieve more useful informations about our visits, but we encountered a serious issue : **Piwik counts more than twice visits on the B page than on the A page**.

Does anyone have any idea about why I have 2x more visits on B page  **in Piwik**, when split gives me equal redirect counts ?

- Is it the redirect 302 that is generating more visits ? (piwik tracking should not be loaded before the redirection, so I don't think so)
- Or it is my Piwik API requests that are badly crafted ? (That is way much more possible)

Here is the Piwik API request details :

- I use the Piwik API to retreive the stats with the method `VisitsSummary.get`
- The pages are named :

  - Page A : `http://my_domain.com/my_page`
  - Page B : `http://my_domain.com/my_page-2`
- I crafted 2 segments to retrieve the stats of both pages :

  - Segment A : `segment=pageUrl==http://my_domain.com/my_page,pageUrl=@http://my_domain.com/my_page?`
  - Segment B : `segment=pageUrl==http://my_domain.com/my_page-2,pageUrl=@http://my_domain.com/my_page-2?`
- Example of a full API request, for page B : `http://piwik.seniormedia.fr/?module=API&format=JSON&token_auth=xxx&method=VisitsSummary.get&idSite=1&period=day&date=2016-02-15,2016-02-15&segment=pageUrl==http://my_domain.com/my_page-2,pageUrl=@http://my_domain.com/my_page-2?`

-> Piwik API documentation : http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api#VisitsSummary

Any help will be welcomed.